# How to stop a do-while loop in this instance

Tags: do-while

Here is the code. I need to be able to stop the loop when ALL 3 of the entered sides are 0, not just 1 or 2. If 1 or 2 of the entered sides are 0 then it should prompt the user again. Is there an operator that will terminate the program when ALL 3 conditions are met?

Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program2
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Read user inputs
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    // User inputed sides of triangle
    double side1, side2, side3;


    // Opening messages
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\tTriangle Identifier Program");
    System.out.print("This program will tell you what type of tringle you have,");
    System.out.println("\nif it is a right triangle, and the area of the triangle.");
    System.out.println("Use input of 0 0 0 to terminate the program.\n");

    do
    {
        // Get sides
        System.out.print("Enter side 1 of the triangle: ");
        side1 = key.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter side 2 of the triangle: ");
        side2 = key.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter side 3 of the triangle: ");
        side3 = key.nextInt();

        double longest = 0;
        double shorter1 = 0;
        double shorter2 = 0;

        if (side1 == 0 || side2 == 0 || side3 == 0)
            System.out.println("These numbers do not satisfy the triangle inequality. Please try again.");

        // Find the largest side 
        if(side1 > side2 && side1 > side3)
        {
            longest = side1;
            shorter1 = side2;
            shorter2 = side3;
        }
        if(side2 > side1 && side2 > side3)
        {
            longest = side2;
            shorter1 = side1;
            shorter2 = side3;
        }
        if(side3 > side2 && side3 > side1)
        {
            longest = side3;
            shorter1 = side1;
            shorter2 = side2;
        }
        if(side1 > 0 && side2 > 0 && side3 > 0)
        {
            if(side1==side2 && side2==side3 && side3==side1)
                System.out.println("The triangle is equilateral");
            if((side1==side2 && side2!=side3) || (side2==side3 && side2!=side1) || (side1==side3 && side2 !=side3))
                System.out.println("The triangle is isosceles");
            if(side1 != side2 && side2 != side3 && side1 != side3)
                System.out.println("The triangle is scalene");
            if(longest == Math.sqrt((shorter1*shorter1)+(shorter2*shorter2)))
                System.out.println("The triangle is a right triangle");
            else
                System.out.println("The tringle is not a right triangle");
        }



    } while (side1 != 0 & side2 != 0 & side3 != 0);



}

}
```

Comment: Using break keyword

Comment: Add another if  if (side1 == 0 &&  side2 == 0 && side3 == 0){break;} hand other values in else part if it all 3 are not equal to 0

Comment: @NagaSaiA Worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: added the do while part.. hope this works for you :)

Comment: any luck Alec Bartley?

Answer (score 0):

Add another if condition to check whether all 3 are 0.
    do
        {
            // Get sides
            System.out.print("Enter side 1 of the triangle: ");
            side1 = key.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter side 2 of the triangle: ");
            side2 = key.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter side 3 of the triangle: ");
            side3 = key.nextInt();

```
        double longest = 0;
        double shorter1 = 0;
        double shorter2 = 0;
        if (side1 == 0 && side2 == 0 && side3 == 0){
                break;
         } else{


        if (side1 == 0 || side2 == 0 || side3 == 0)
            System.out.println("These numbers do not satisfy the triangle inequality. Please try again.");

        // Find the largest side 
        if(side1 > side2 && side1 > side3)
        {
            longest = side1;
            shorter1 = side2;
            shorter2 = side3;
        }
        if(side2 > side1 && side2 > side3)
        {
            longest = side2;
            shorter1 = side1;
            shorter2 = side3;
        }
        if(side3 > side2 && side3 > side1)
        {
            longest = side3;
            shorter1 = side1;
            shorter2 = side2;
        }
        if(side1 > 0 && side2 > 0 && side3 > 0)
        {
            if(side1==side2 && side2==side3 && side3==side1)
                System.out.println("The triangle is equilateral");
            if((side1==side2 && side2!=side3) || (side2==side3 && side2!=side1) || (side1==side3 && side2 !=side3))
                System.out.println("The triangle is isosceles");
            if(side1 != side2 && side2 != side3 && side1 != side3)
                System.out.println("The triangle is scalene");
            if(longest == Math.sqrt((shorter1*shorter1)+(shorter2*shorter2)))
                System.out.println("The triangle is a right triangle");
            else
                System.out.println("The tringle is not a right triangle");
        }

}

    } while (side1 != 0 & side2 != 0 & side3 != 0);
```